# Custom CSS Coding/Coding Block for a Website

Tags: css, squarespace, graphical-logo

I have a question about Custom CSS or using a coding block when uploading an image to a page as a logo. I am using squarespace for my website and I need help coding my logo so that it fits on every page. An option is to use Custom CSS or a coding block. I am using the Rally template for Squarespace and my logo has a max capacity unfortunately. What coding do I use to have my logo on each page? My site is www.goodemoments.com. Please help, I would like to officially launch my blog very soon!!

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your problem here. Please take a look at the article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in Squarespace, the way to put your logo on every page is to use it in the header. That is true for the Rally template as well.

To do this:

1. Add your logo via edit mode by going to Design > Logo & Title >
   Logo Image
2. Save
3. The logo will now be used in place of your title ("Goode Moments
   | Lifestyle Blog")
4. Go to the Style Editor: Design > Style Editor
5. Under "HEADER: BRANDING", adjust the "Logo Width" parameter to
   your liking.

Once you've done this, it may then make sense to add some custom CSS via the CSS Editor if some additional minor tweaking is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so I would like to use Custom CSS, because my logo that I will be using is to small. The width only goes to a certain size and I want it to be larger.